# Where can I ask a question about SoundCloud (not related to programming)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about SoundCloud which is not related to programming.

What is the right Stack Exchange site for this?

Comment: What question would that be? We do need some details about what your question is, rather than just what it isn't?

Comment: I found [this](https://soundcloud.com/djsfrommars/tracks) user on soundcloud. He has 73k followers. But his latest track (which is already 7 months old) only has 5 likes and 0 comments. How is this possible?

Comment: Not sure anyone's going to be able to answer that.

Comment: Somega - They have a couple 3 years old: https://soundcloud.com/djsfrommars/stronger  https://soundcloud.com/djsfrommars/dont-come-back-original-mix with less than 50 plays and no comments. The way you do that on YouTube is upload as private, leave that way for years, make public. If SC allows upload to be private then there's one explanation. Only an opinion, you'd need to ask SC.

Answer (score 4):

SoundCloud qualifies as a [web application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud) and (without seeing your actual question) [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) might be a good fit. Please use the search function (your question might have been asked already) and if not, check their [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking your question.

SoundCloud has mobile apps, so if your question is specific to one of those apps, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit.